# Android Updating UI from AsycTask after Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am using AsyncTask to retrieve some data from Server which is displayed on the screen. The issue is if I change the orientation of the device while data is being retreieved (a progress bar being displayed), my UI does not get updated.

I have done following to handle this situation:

a) override onRetainNonConfigurationInstance which returns the instance of my AsychTask, retrieve this on onCreate method.
b) Declared my widgets as volatile
c) Redraw the entire U by calling setContentView from postExecute of the AsycTask
d) invoked invalidate method on the widgets

I do not get any errors on screen, my application does not crashed but the UI is not updated either.
I have executed the code on debug mode, the code which updates the UI is actually executed, but it does nothing.

In logs I see one error saying my Activity has leaked a window.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong or not doing something which I should be doing.

Comment: Is your AsyncTask hanging on to UI objects from the dead Activity? Sounds like your postExecute() code is acting on the old Activity, not the new one...

Comment: I think some code would help...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly that your AsyncTask is keeping a reference to the old Activity. (Perhaps it's an inner class?) This is a surprisingly difficult problem. There's an excellent discussion of the difficulties, as well as some solutions, on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/vwRrlc84gy0/discussion) at Google groups. Scroll down for the answers by Lance Nanek for some code that gets around this.

The problem is not specific to AsyncTask; it can happen with any background thread that needs to interact with the UI and also needs to survive the destroy/start lifecycle events that come with a configuration change.